# Redis not caching, going to MongoDB every time instead

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis

I'm trying to get Redis up and running and I have the server working. When I run a load test, however, I see that every query is still going to my mongoDB instead of looking at Redis first. My Redis server terminal is this:

```
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:00:00.641 * Background saving terminated with success
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:01:01.074 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:01:01.076 * Background saving started by pid 42406
42406:C 22 Sep 2020 14:01:05.256 * DB saved on disk
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:01:05.305 * Background saving terminated with success
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:02:06.043 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:02:06.052 * Background saving started by pid 42439
42439:C 22 Sep 2020 14:02:10.719 * DB saved on disk
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:02:10.784 * Background saving terminated with success
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:03:11.030 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:03:11.033 * Background saving started by pid 42480
42480:C 22 Sep 2020 14:03:17.592 * DB saved on disk
41136:M 22 Sep 2020 14:03:17.690 * Background saving terminated with success
```

When I look on my New Relic dashboard, however, I see that the response time is very slow (10,000 ms at least) and that's all from MongoDB. Redis only takes up about 15-16ms, the other 10,000 ms is MongoDB.

My MongoDB is indexed correctly, however, as queries there only take 1 millisecond. I also used the .lean() method in my database.js file.

I'm using Artillery for my load testing.

For reference, here is my index.js file for my server:

```
require('newrelic');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Images = require('../database-mongo/index.js');
const cors = require('cors');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
const RedisServer = require('redis-server');

const server = new RedisServer(6379);
const PORT = 3003;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../react-client/dist'));

server.open((err) => {
  if (err === null) {
    console.log('redis server working')
  }
})

let redisMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  let key = "__expIress__" + req.originalUrl || req.url;
  client.get(key, function (err, reply) {
    if (reply) {
      res.send(reply);
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send;
      res.send = (body) => {
        client.set(key, JSON.stringify(body));
        res.sendResponse(body);
      }
      next();
    }
  });
};


app.get('/images/urls/:itemId', redisMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  Images.fetchItemImages(Number(req.params.itemId))
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        res.status(200).send({ data });
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error with app.get: ', err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app
```

Here is my index.js file for my database:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/images', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongoose connection error: ', err);
});

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('mongoose connected successfully');
});

const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemId: Number,
  pic1Small: String,
  pic1Med: String,
  pic1Large: String,
  pic2Small: String,
  pic2Med: String,
  pic2Large: String
});

const Image = mongoose.model('url', imageSchema);


function fetchItemImages(itemId) {
  // console.log('fetchImages invoked')
  return Image.find({ 'itemId': Number(itemId) }).lean()
}

module.exports = Image;
module.exports.fetchItemImages = fetchItemImages;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to it. Two parts are missing. First, the Redis middleware needs to have a a line that parses the JSON when it gets returned, so it should look like this:

```
let redisMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  let key = "__expIress__" + req.originalUrl || req.url;
  client.get(key, function (err, reply) {
    if (reply) {
      res.send(JSON.parse(reply));
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send;
      res.send = (body) => {
        client.set(key, JSON.stringify(body));
        res.sendResponse(body);
      }
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

Second, the GET request needs to have the .set method assuming there's data in the Redis database.

```
app.get('/images/urls/:itemId', redisMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  db.fetchItemImages(req.params.itemId)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        client.set(req.params.itemId, JSON.stringify({ data }))
        res.status(200).send({ data });
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error with app.get: ', err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    })
})
```

What happened was nothing was getting saved to Redis, so while Redis was being checked for every test in the artillery test, nothing was entered into Redis.